# Which contrast to compare all group means to zero?

Tags: linear-model, contrasts

I suffer from a momentary confusion. Given a regression model, specified in R as

```
lm(Y ~ group)
```

where group is a factor with several levels, how should I code the contrasts such that for each group level, I test whether the group mean is significantly different from zero?

Answer (score 1):

I said - momentary.

```
lm(Y ~ 0 + group)
```

Never mind me. Move along, nothing to see.